# How can I use passthrough/reverse-tether on the HTC One V with Ubuntu?

Tags: reverse-tether, htc-one-v

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you set up internet pass-through (reverse-tether) on linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/how-do-you-set-up-internet-pass-through-reverse-tether-on-linux)

I read that the phone needs to be connected to HTC Sync, thats not available for Linux. Has anybody been able to do a passthrough?

Comment: [Create wifi hotspot in Ubuntu](http://freshtutorial.com/create-your-own-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-11-10/) and connect your Android device with this..

Comment: I cant make a hotspot. Using 12.04. Phone cant detect the AP.

Comment: Look for how to create hotspot in Ubuntu 12.04. Ask at superuser.com if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Q&As already available here which probably help you in getting started. The probably most usefuls include:

- [How do you set up internet pass-through ( reverse - tether ) on linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/how-do-you-set-up-internet-pass-through-reverse-tether-on-linux)
- [Use USB as network access for an Android device ( reverse tethering)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/use-usb-as-network-access-for-an-android-device-reverse-tethering)
- [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

There are also some apps available on the Playstore which could prove helpful, e.g.:

- [Reverse Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.littlelan.ReverseTether.Trial) (requires root)
- [USB Reverse Tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jasongong.tether.usb) (requires root)

As far as it looks to me, reverse tethering alsways seems to require root. Also, if your computer just provides ad-hoc network -- without root (and some special tricks) most Android devices are not able to use that.