# Internet sharing - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, internet, usb-tethering

I have a smartphone (from a local manufacturer). It has an option saying 'USB Internet' with description 'Sharing windows PC internet via USB cable'.

My first question is whether I can bridge my Ubuntu internet connection with this option?

When I connect my phone to my PC Network Manager show a new ethernet connection 'Wired Connection2' with name 'Ethernet Network (Qmobile A36)'. The problem is that network manager try to connect to this network but always fails to do so.
I tried to apply every solution available on internet but failed to gain any success.

Output for `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 0bb4:0004 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)
...
```

Output for `ip link show`:

```
...
9: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a2:d4:38:5b:d8:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output for `ifconfig usb0`:

```
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a2:d4:38:5b:d8:72  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a0d4:38ff:fe5b:d872/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7104 (7.1 KB)  TX bytes:86559 (86.5 KB)
```

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use the phone's internet connection from the PC, or the PC's internet connection from the phone?

Comment: PC's internet connection to phone..!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set up internet pass-through (reverse-tether) on linux?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/how-do-you-set-up-internet-pass-through-reverse-tether-on-linux)

Comment: @DanHulme I have tried that solution too. But no gain.

Comment: Did you do the manual assignment of an IP to `usb0`? (Because your `ifconfig` output depicts otherwise.) This explains the process in a bit more detailed way: http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/networking/guide-connect-android-to-linux-pc-t2825476 (I just tried it and got the PC to connect to the interface flawlessly; however, I had to use the Edit Connections option of Network Manager for assigning the IP, instead of the command line.)